# PDF.Convert.ToXod exception with PDFTron PDFNet on WinService

Tags: pdf, pdftron, pdfnet

I try to use the PDF.Convert.ToXod to convert file as .xod, but it occurs exception, the exception as below:

Exception:

```
 Message: An error occurred while converting the file.
```

Detailed error:

```
The dictionary does not contain required key: VRes
 Conditional expression: false
 Filename   : Convert.cpp
 Function   : trn::PDF::Convert::ToPdf
 Linenumber : 1679
```

Who have any ideas on it?

Comment: Does this occur with any document, or only certain ones? This is almost certainly a document specific issue (the document is malformed/non-conforming) so you should send the document in question to PDFTron support.

Comment: I use the latest version PDFNet version 6.7.1.52203 to convert files, it can not be converted the .bmp, .jp2, .gif.  So I roll back the previous version 6.6.2.42730, all of files type works well. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

This has been corrected in the release channel, and official downloads will be updated soon. In the meantime, please contact [support](https://www.pdftron.com/support/reportproblem.html) at pdftron to get a build with the fix. Be sure to include exactly what version you need (e.g. .Net 4 64bit)

Or, as a workaround if you don't want to update versions, is to follow the [AddImageTest](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/samplecode/AddImageTest.cs.html) sample project, which will not hit this error.